# how do i include another project in github

Tags: github, repository, fork

I have created a plugin for a javascript library and want to upload this to github as a new project.  Within my plugin directory, i include the current code for the javascript plugin.

So it's easy for users to get my plugin plus the javascript library, i thought i would include the javascript project inside my directory.   My intention was not to make changes to the js library but to allow the user to download my project and get the latest version of the js library at the same time.

I could do this manually by forking the js library project into my directory and then syncing it each time a new version comes out but is there a way to do this automatically ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out git submodule, it does exactly what you describe!

Comment: If its only for readonly purposes, do you know if i can specify a non git repository like bitbucket ?

Comment: No, you can't - you could *try* a post-receive hook that runs hg for you whenever you fetch a repo, but that might be unreliable